# Yii2: How to use ActionEvent

Tags: php, yii2

Can't find any information how to use ActionEvent. I need to get result of execution - just example how to get result of triggering Event. According to documentation, I can use ActionEvent instead Event for it.

Official documentation for plain Event:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Component;
use yii\base\Event;

class Foo extends Component
{
    const EVENT_HELLO = 'hello';

    public function bar()
    {
       $this->trigger(self::EVENT_HELLO);
    }
}
```

...binding event:

```
$foo = new Foo;

$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, [$object, 'methodName']);
```

Comment: Execution of what? How do you want to use it?

Comment: Just need example to get result of event after triggering it

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/89c9703283b3ea306b44a8f275f325bafab77833/framework/base/Controller.php#L299-L305 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use custom event, you should pass it as second argument of [`trigger()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-component#trigger()-detail):

```
$event = new MyEvent();
$event->helloMessage = $someValue;
$this->trigger(self::EVENT_HELLO, $event);
$isValid = $event->customEventResult;
```

This is explained in [guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events#triggering-events). You may take a look how `ActionEvent` is used in [`Controller::afterAction()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#afterAction()-detail):

```
public function afterAction($action, $result)
{
    $event = new ActionEvent($action);
    $event->result = $result;
    $this->trigger(self::EVENT_AFTER_ACTION, $event);
    return $event->result;
}
```

BTW: `ActionEvent` is designed to control [controller action flow](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-lifecycle) - you should not use it for different purposes. You may want to create separate `Event` class if you need to handle custom event.